# Showing that there exists a set of vectors, such that multiplied by a matrix, we'll get the orthonormal basis for the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal

I wanna show that if I have a matrix $A \in Mat_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ of rank n, and we let $(b_1,b_2,b_3,...,b_n)$ be an orthonormal basis for the space Col(A) (w.r.t. the standard dot product on $\mathbb{R}^m$), then there exists a set of vectors $(c_1,c_2,c_3,...,c_n)$, such that $A\cdot c_i = b_i$ for $i=1,2,3,...,n$.

I'm pretty sure that the c vectors should be somehow comprised of some kind of inverse b that takes the part of $a_i$ going in the direction of $b_i$, but I'm not really sure how to proceed with the task of showing this, or how to make this a bit more concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way of thinking about it.

Let $ B $ be an orthonormal basis for the column space of $ A $.  Then each column of $ A $ can be written as a linear combination of the columns of $ B $.
If $ A = \left( \begin{array}{c c c} a_1 & a_2 & \cdots \end{array} \right) $ exposes the columns of $ A $ then there is a vector $ x_i $ such that $ B x_i  = a_i $.
But then
$$
\left( \begin{array}{c c c} B x_1 & B x_2 & \cdots \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{c c c} a_1 & a_2 & \cdots \end{array} \right) 
$$ or, equivalently,
$$ B \left( \begin{array}{c c c} x_1 & x_2 & \cdots \end{array} \right)  = \left( \begin{array}{c c c} a_1 & a_2 & \cdots \end{array} \right) 
$$
So, the matrix you want is given by 
$$ X = \left( \begin{array}{c c c}  x_1 &  x_2 & \cdots \end{array} \right) $$.

Comment: Right, so that in essence we'd have that AX = B in the end, but how do I go about showing a bit more specifically that there indeed does exist these $x_1,x_2,...$? It seems intuitive that they exist since each entry in A is just a combination of the vectors in B, and thus there must exist some inverse combination that'll revert the A entry to the original B entry, but going from intuition to a concrete "show that they exist" is where I'm currently stuck at

Comment: One immediate consequence of AX = B would be that if we do the AX multiplication we'd get something like this:

$B = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1x_1 & a_1x_2 & a_1x_3 & \dots  & a_1x_n \\
    a_2x_1 & a_2x_2 & a_2x_3 & \dots  & a_2x_n \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_mx_1 & a_mx_2 & a_mx_3 & \dots  & a_mx_n
\end{bmatrix}$

when multiplying it out. But then theres the whole converting that to the specific $b_i$

Comment: It is a consequence of the fact that the columns of $B$ form an orthonormal basis.  Are you saying you are supposed to give a formula?  Let's see: $ B X = A $.  $ B $ has orthonormal columns.  So $ B^T B X = B^T A $.  But $ B^T B = I $ (the identity).  So, $ X = B^T A $.

Comment: Right, yeah okay, but then since we're interested in the matrix that we can take as Y in this: $AY = B$, would that then be the inverse of the X you've found there? So that it'd be $AX^{-1} = B$ I guess? As yours seem to go $BX = A$ and I'm more interested in the other way, as later subtasks are things as "show that $A\cdot C = B$" and "Show that $B^T \cdot B = I$" and so on for a few different things. 

But yeah they're not specifically asking for a formula, but the question is stated as "Show that there exists, for i=1,2,...,n, a vector $c_i$ such that $A\cdot c_i = b_i$"

Comment: Sure.   Or you can say $ A Y = B $ hence $ A^T A Y = A^T B $ and hence $ Y = ( A^T A )^{-1} A^T B $.   There are a number of ways of skinning this cat.

Comment: Okay so I've used this way of isolating C/Y whichever we want to call it. But getting to showing that $A\cdot C$ is actually equal to $B$ is hard now, since I've used this to derive C in the first place. This makes me think that I've got to derive a way to show that there exists individual $c_i$ vectors before making a matrix out of it. Do you have any input on this? Would also just like to say thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: OK, so you start with $ A y_i = b_i $ and then $ A^T A y_i = A^T b_i $, after which $ y_i = ( A^T A )^{-1} A^T b_i $.  If you then put it into a matrix, you get back to what I suggested before.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about the linear map $L: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ that corresponds to your matrix $A$, you have the identity that $\text{Col}(A) = \text{Im}(L)$, or, in words, that the column space of your matrix is equal to the image of the map. Since $b_1, \dotsc,b_n \in \text{Im}(L)$ there are, by definition of $\text{Im}(A)$, vectors $c_1, \dotsc, c_n$ in the domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ that map to them, i.e. that $b_j = L(c_j)$ for each $j$ (this is a property of maps in general, not just of linear maps on vector spaces).

Translate $L$ back into its matrix representation and you get that $b_j = A\cdot c_j$ for all $j = 1, \dotsc, n$, as desired.

Comment: So in essence, you're saying that since B is a basis for A, we can use A as a transformation matrix for a linear map. And since we've already made clear that A can be construed from B, it's effectively a linear map using basis B, and given some vectors in the domain of the map (here, the C vectors) must map to the B vectors?

I'm still not seeing the whole "Show" thing, because I'd assume that it can be shown in a less abstract way, can't it?